# pandas read_html ValueError: No tables found

Tags: python, html, pandas, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap the historical weather data from the "https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KMAHADLE7#history/tdata/s20170201/e20170201/mcustom.html" weather underground page. I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 

page_link = 'https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KMAHADLE7#history/tdata/s20170201/e20170201/mcustom.html'
df = pd.read_html(page_link)
print(df)
```

I have the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "weather_station_scrapping.py", line 11, in <module>
  result = pd.read_html(page_link)
 File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 987, in read_html
  displayed_only=displayed_only)
 File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 815, in _parse raise_with_traceback(retained)
 File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 403, in raise_with_traceback
  raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
ValueError: No tables found
```

Although, this page clearly has a table but it is not being picked by the read_html. I have tried using Selenium so that the page can be loaded before I read it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KMAHADLE7#history/tdata/s20170201/e20170201/mcustom.html")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("history_table")

head = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('thead')
body = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')

list_rows = []

for items in body.find_element_by_tag_name('tr'):
    list_cells = []
    for item in items.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
        list_cells.append(item.text)
    list_rows.append(list_cells)
driver.close()
```

Now, the problem is that it cannot find "tr". I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The table doesn't exist in the page html, it loads asynchronously after the rest of the page. Pandas doesn;t wait for the page to load java content. You may need some sort of automation like Selenium to load the page before trying to parse it

Comment: Hi, I have tried using Selenium but I am still facing issues. Would you mind taking a look at my edit and suggest any suggestions if possible.

Comment: Different selector `df=pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_id("history_table").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]` See my answer posted below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `requests` and avoid opening browser.

You can get current conditions by using:

https://stationdata.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/stationlookup?station=KMAHADLE7&units=both&v=2.0&format=json&callback=jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014&_=15

and strip of `'jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014('` from the left and `')'` from the right. Then handle the json string.

You can get summary and history by calling the API with the following

https://api-ak.wunderground.com/api/606f3f6977348613/history_20170201null/units:both/v:2.0/q/pws:KMAHADLE7.json?callback=jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885015&_=1542743886276

You then need to strip `'jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885015('` from the front and `');'` from the right. You then have a JSON string you can parse.

Sample of JSON:

[image]

You can find these URLs by using F12 dev tools in browser and inspecting the network tab for the traffic created during page load.

An example for `current`, noting there seems to be a problem with `nulls` in the JSON so I am replacing with `"placeholder"`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://stationdata.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/stationlookup?station=KMAHADLE7&units=both&v=2.0&format=json&callback=jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014&_=15'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
s = soup.select('html')[0].text.strip('jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014(').strip(')')
s = s.replace('null','"placeholder"')
data= json.loads(s)
data = json_normalize(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's a solution using selenium for browser automation

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get('https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KMAHADLE7#history/tdata/s20170201/e20170201/mcustom.html')
    df=pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_id("history_table").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]

Time    Temperature Dew Point   Humidity    Wind    Speed   Gust    Pressure  Precip. Rate. Precip. Accum.  UV  Solar
0   12:02 AM    25.5 °C 18.7 °C 75 %    East    0 kph   0 kph   29.3 hPa    0 mm    0 mm    0   0 w/m²
1   12:07 AM    25.5 °C 19 °C   76 %    East    0 kph   0 kph   29.31 hPa   0 mm    0 mm    0   0 w/m²
2   12:12 AM    25.5 °C 19 °C   76 %    East    0 kph   0 kph   29.31 hPa   0 mm    0 mm    0   0 w/m²
3   12:17 AM    25.5 °C 18.7 °C 75 %    East    0 kph   0 kph   29.3 hPa    0 mm    0 mm    0   0 w/m²
4   12:22 AM    25.5 °C 18.7 °C 75 %    East    0 kph   0 kph   29.3 hPa    0 mm    0 mm    0   0 w/m²
```

Editing with breakdown of exactly what's happening, since the above one-liner is actually not very good self-documenting code:

After setting up the driver, we select the table with its ID value (Thankfully this site actually uses reasonable and descriptive IDs)

```
tab=driver.find_element_by_id("history_table")
```

Then, from that element, we get the HTML instead of the web driver element object

```
tab_html=tab.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

We use pandas to parse the html

```
tab_dfs=pd.read_html(tab_html)
```

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/io.html#io-read-html):

> "read_html returns a list of DataFrame objects, even if there is only
>   a single table contained in the HTML content"

So we index into that list with the only table we have, at index zero

```
df=tab_dfs[0]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. This works wonders, but I would highly appreciate if you would shed a little light on why did we select an attribute and picked the value at index 0.

Comment: Edited with breakdown

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful.