# Python Pandas cannot grab Financial Table using pd.read_table()?

Tags: python, pandas, html-table

I am trying to grab the financial table on "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/1928.HK/financials?p=1928.HK". I tried pd.read_json() and pd.read_html, but both nothing were downloaded. I tried pd.read_table(). Some content is download, but not the financial table.

my codes:

```
import pandas as pd

url =   "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/1928.HK/financials?p=1928.HK"

df = pd.read_table(url)
print(df)
df.to_excel("test1.xlsx")
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360166/pandas-read-html-no-tables-found , may be try with the answer in the link

Comment: Tried. only the small table on right hand side is downloaded. The main financial data table is not downloaded.