# Python - Web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and am trying to scrape data from the following site.  Although this code worked for a different site i cannot get it to work for nextgen stats.  anyone have any thoughts as to why? below is my code and the error i am getting

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import html5lib

urlwk1 = 'https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/receiving/2020/1'
urlwk2 = 'https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/receiving/2020/2'

df11 = pd.read_html(urlwk1)
df11[0].to_csv ('NFL_Receiving_Page1.csv', index=False) #index false gets rid of index listing that appears as the very first column in the csv
```

Below is the error I am getting

> > > df11 = pd.read_html(urlwk1)
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "C:\Users\USERX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line
> > > 296, in wrapper
> > > return func(*args, **kwargs)
> > > File "C:\Users\USERX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1101, in
> > > read_html
> > > displayed_only=displayed_only,
> > > File "C:\Users\USERX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 917, in _parse
> > > raise retained
> > > File "C:\Users\USERX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 898, in _parse
> > > tables = p.parse_tables()
> > > File "C:\Users\USERX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 217, in parse_tables
> > > tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
> > > File "C:\Users\USERX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 547, in _parse_tables
> > > raise ValueError("No tables found")
> > > ValueError: No tables found
> > > df11[0].to_csv ('NFL_Receiving_Page1.csv', index=False) #index false gets rid of index listing that appears as the very first column in the csv
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > NameError: name 'df11' is not defined

Comment: We can't quite tell from that error exactly what's going on, but if it works on one site it's not guaranteed to work on the other as the structure is quite likely different.  Are you familiar with using the debugger library? Have you checked what `df11[0]` is in the context above?

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the error i'm getting and provided exactly what it looks like. 
df11 is supposed to contain the scraped dataframe.

Comment: I am not familiar with the dubugger library

Comment: Can you show us the output of df11?

Comment: The error shared above is the output i get when i run the df11 line

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `pandas.read_html` is not capable of parsing dynamically loading html tables.

This [page](https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/receiving/2020/2) is fetching that table data using an API call

You can use this below code to fetch and parse the API response

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
}

response = requests.get('https://appapi.ngs.nfl.com/statboard/receiving?season=2020&seasonType=REG&week=2', headers=headers)

df = pd.read_json(response.content)
df.to_csv ('NFL_Receiving_Page1.csv', index=False)
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/WellmadeWiseHashfunction)

Answer (score 0):

[Read HTML using Selenium Driver and read html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360166/pandas-read-html-no-tables-found)

I think the page address you mentioned is dynamically loading. Please refer to the post above and then try the code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chromedriver_path = '/home/user/chromedriver'

d = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
d.get('https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/receiving/2020/1')
time.sleep(3)
html = d.page_source
df = pd.read_html(html)
```

After you properly install chrome driver in whatever system you have, this code will work. Try setting time.sleep() as per your internet speed and chromedrive path as in your system.