# Problem faced while scraping tables from my university site using pandas read_html()

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am working on a project which requires web scraping from my university site. The university site is https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/OneView/OneView.aspx . When I enter the roll no(ex- 1513310*** *** from 001 to 100), the result gets shown but when I copy the URL and paste again in the browser it redirects me to entering roll no again. I assume the same things happening while fetching it from pd.read_html() function. Is there any way to bypass it?

```
import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_html('https://erp.aktu.ac.in/WebPages/OneView/OVEngine.aspx?enc=NnCOpTxI4+e2v6OtxoLaIVhtGRRyQHWhl51tE9IxJAlzwgkcwHudd8EEQQF6+chV')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1100, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 915, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 895, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 545, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

The error is shown because the result page cannot be obtained. Is there any solution around it?

Comment: The reason is you need to login in order to view the result.. Pandas html_reader can't handle sessions.. you can use python request along with BeautifulSoup to screape the page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398785/pandas-read-html-valueerror-no-tables-found this question can be helpful in your case