# pandas read_html / no tables found

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some problems with pandas read_html. When I tried to read the table using pandas, it wouldn't work. So I tried using requests and BeautifulSoup and solved the problem. But I would like to know why it was not possible for me to get the table using pandas at the first time. Thank you.

first code

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930&page=1'
r = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

second code that i tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

ulr = 'https://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930&page=1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
table = str(soup.select("table"))
data=pd.read_html(table)[0]
```

Comment: You can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398785/pandas-read-html-valueerror-no-tables-found) thread.

Comment: The pandas read_html will be available with three library installations: lxml, html5lib, and beautifulsoup4.

Comment: You should try to say what happened. Did you get any error message? What were you expecting and what you got? These information will help to understand your problem.