# Scrape table with pandas read_html: 'ValueError: No tables found'

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I wanted to try use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table) (in the updated answer) to scrape the table on [this](http://www.peptide-ligand.cn/show/13) page.

When I inspect the webpage, I can see there is a table on the page. However when I try to use the method from a previous SO answer by doing:

```
for i in range(10,15):
    webpage = 'http://www.peptide-ligand.cn/show/' + str(i)
    r = requests.get(webpage)
    df_list = pd.read_html(r.text) # this should all the tables in webpages to a list according to previous SO answer
    df = df_list[0]
    print(df)
```

The output is

```
raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

But I can see from inspecting the page that there is a table? Could someone point to where I'm going wrong?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398785/pandas-read-html-valueerror-no-tables-found) answer, but I don't understand why i'd have to use selenium, and the above method doesn't work.

Comment: You start at "http://www.peptide-ligand.cn/show/10" which does _not_ have a table. You lookup 10, 11, 12, 13, 14. Only 12 and 13 have tables...

Comment: What a stupid mistake, so sorry thanks a mil.