# Value Error using pandas while webscraping

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this timetable for a college project but get error saying ValueError : No tables found. I am using pandas to scrape this website

```
timetable = pd.read_html('https://opentimetable.dcu.ie/')[0]
print(timetable)
```

The website i am trying to scrape is : https://opentimetable.dcu.ie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer says, this method won't wait for the page to load so you'd need to use something like Selenium.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398785/pandas-read-html-valueerror-no-tables-found) answer seems to be doing exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

This page have a load screen, and `pd.read_html()` read the first html he gets (the load screen html without any tables).

You can try get the tables using a scraping library, like `selenium`.