# Python Pandas - read_html No tables Found

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I am very new to python and trying to do my own data analysis.

I am trying to parse data from this website:
https://www.tsn.ca/nhl/statistics

I wanted to get the table in a data frame format.

I tried this:

`import pandas as pd`

`players_list_unclean = pd.read_html('https://www.sportsnet.ca/hockey/nhl/players/?season=2021&?seasonType=reg&tab=Skaters')`

I get the following error:

raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found

I can see there is table, but for some reason it is not being read.

I found another stack overflow solution recommending using selenium:

[pandas read_html ValueError: No tables found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398785/pandas-read-html-valueerror-no-tables-found)

However, when I tried to implement this code I could not find the table ID in the html page source. Does anyone know another way to do this? I have tried other websites, but I ultimately have the same issue.

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KMAHADLE7#history/tdata/s20170201/e20170201/mcustom.html")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("history_table")

head = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('thead')
body = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')

list_rows = []

for items in body.find_element_by_tag_name('tr'):
    list_cells = []
    for item in items.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
        list_cells.append(item.text)
    list_rows.append(list_cells)
driver.close() ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no table but you're in luck because the data is coming from a fetch:

https://datacrunch.9c9media.ca/statsapi/sports/hockey/leagues/nhl/sortablePlayerSeasonStats/skater?brand=tsn&type=json&seasonType=regularSeason&season=2021

Comment: Does that mean I just have to manually clean the data from the html file?

Comment: No, that's json data you parse it with json.loads

Comment: Ok, and how did you get this fetch data from the link you sent above?

Comment: The same way. With requests or any other way you're getting the html

Comment: Sorry I am not quite following. I was just using read_html. I am guessing you can't do that to get the fetch data?

Comment: Here, try one of [these ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script)

Answer (score 2):

If you right click the table and choose inspect, you will see that the "table" on that page is not actually using the html table element.

From the Pandas documentation:

> This function searches for <table> elements and only for <tr> and <th> rows and <td> elements within each <tr> or <th> element in the table.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

I don't think this will work on this page. Probably need to find another data source.